# how to append rows of an empty column with dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a column `df["id"]` that has 53000 ids(rows) as `str` type. I want to append them to third column `df['ID']` but in the form of dictionaries in each row: `{'id':'id from the column df[id']}`.

```
df['ID']=''
for i in range(0,len(df['id'])):
    x = {'id' : 'df['id'][i]'}
    df['ID'] = df['ID'].append(x)
```

`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

Comment: I see answer was reaccept, what was reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
df['ID'] = [{'id': x} for x in df['id']]
```

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']})

df['ID'] = [{'id': x} for x in df['id']]
```

[out]

```
    id             ID
0  id1  {'id': 'id1'}
1  id2  {'id': 'id2'}
2  id3  {'id': 'id3'}
3  id4  {'id': 'id4'}
```

Comment: now what if i want to put each dictionaries in list? how to do that @Chris A

Comment: can you give an example? Maybe update your answer with the desired list you need

Comment: @AamerAshfaque nice one :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3]})

df['ID'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: {'id':x})

print (df)
   id         ID
0   1  {'id': 1}
1   2  {'id': 2}
2   3  {'id': 3}
```